# SQL LIKE and PDO bindParam - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to implement search in my table and I get this nasty SQL error when I try to bind the search variable in my query. Not binding it returns the correct results but don't I need some sort of security? So, I am passing this query along into a class of mine:

```
$query = "SELECT books.id, title, author, category, cover, owns_book.added FROM books JOIN owns_book ON books.id = owns_book.book_id 
  WHERE owns_book.u_id ='" . $_SESSION['user_session'] . "'";
```

The query in the class can be accessed with `$this->query`
I store more things in the class like result limit and so on and everything works as intended prior to my attempt to add search functionality.

All further work with the query is done in this method:

```
public function getData($page = 1, $limit=5, $orderBy='added' , $order='desc', $search="test"){
    $this->limit = $limit;
    $this->page = $page;
    $this->query .= " AND title LIKE :keyword OR author LIKE  :keyword 
        OR category LIKE :keyword OR owns_book.added LIKE  :keyword";
    $columns = array('author', 'title', 'category', 'added');
    $orderType =  array('asc', 'desc');
    if(in_array($orderBy, $columns) & in_array($order, $orderType)) $this->query .= " ORDER BY $orderBy $order";
    if ( $this->limit == 'all' ) {
        $query = $this->query;
    }else{
        $this->row_start = ( ( $this->page - 1 ) * $this->limit );
        $query = $this->query.
            " LIMIT :rowStart, :limit";
    }
    $search = "%".$search."%";
    echo $query;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":keyword", $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":rowStart", $this->row_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":limit", $this->limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    //doing further work with the result
}
```

Binding rowStart and limit work as intended, only keyword binding throws and error and I don't understand why. I tried different things, for example trying with `LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%')`
would still throw the same error.

I tried changing `$search = "%".$search."%";` to `$search = "'%".$search."%'";`, still the same error.

```
echo $query;
```

Returns this:

> SELECT books.id, title, author, category, cover, owns_book.added FROM books JOIN owns_book ON books.id = owns_book.book_id WHERE owns_book.u_id ='57' AND title LIKE :keyword OR author LIKE :keyword OR category LIKE :keyword OR owns_book.added LIKE :keyword ORDER BY added desc LIMIT :rowStart, :limit

If I don't bind the search variable and just go like

```
$search = "'%".$search."%'";
$this->query .= " AND title LIKE $search OR author LIKE $search
OR category LIKE $search OR owns_book.added LIKE $search";
```

I get the result I want. But I'm worried that this is not the correct approach.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like

Comment: so your query may contain or not `LIMIT ` clause. but you bind param `:limit` anyway without any check. I'm not 100% sure but PDO may fail to bind all the values to all the placeholders because count is not match. That's why everything works once you "inject" value directly - then counts match.

Comment: what does error message say completely?